# Sort the letter count descending

Tags: python

Beginner's question: This program I made does what I am asked to make, except it does not sort the last letter count in descending order. How do I change the program to do that, please?

```
word = input("Paste the text you want anlysed: ")
import re
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters

print("Word count: {}".format(len(word.split())))
print("Sentences ending with a ".": {}".format(len(re.findall(r'\.', word))))
print("Sentences ending with a "?": {}".format(len(re.findall(r'\?', word))))
print("Sentences ending with a "!": {}".format(len(re.findall(r'\!', word))))
parts = [len(l.split()) for l in re.split(r'[?!.]', word) if l.strip()]
print("Average word count per sentence: {}".format(sum(parts)/len(parts)))

def count_letters(s) :
    filtered = [c for c in s.lower() if c in ascii_letters
    return Counter(filtered)
count_letters(word)
```

Comment: You're lacking closing `]` in `filtered = [c ...`.

Comment: Sorry 'bout the ] ... typo

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74451660/edit) your question. People would normally not correct typos in your code since they could be the source of the problem in many questions (not this one).